# How to add ReactJS to existing node.js backend app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a very simple node.js API

**Structure:**

```
| project-name
|  public
|     index.html
|     ... some static js/css
|  app.js
|  package.json
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  http = require('http');

var app = module.exports = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.route('/api/projects').get(...).post(...)
app.route('/api/sales').get(...).post(...)

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

// Starting express server
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Run server - `node app.js`

**Notice:** It's a learning project, not for production. I just want to figure out how it all work together.

And now I want to add `ReactJS` to this project (actualy to `public/index.html`). But I still want to use `app.js` to run server with it's api, with the same port.

I know how to make "production build" (compile all jsx to js and use as simple scripts). My questions is only about dev server.

I want:

- To run a server (api) and client (reactjs) with only one command (`node app.js` or `nodemon app.js` etc)
- To have an auto-reload after script changes (seems `nodemon` can do it)

Comment: I suggest you to look at [this post](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/). It pretty much explains everything you are trying to learn.

Comment: @bennygenel thanks! great article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Installing React in plain HTML (quick way, dev mode only)

This is not the solution for a production, however, it will do for the first tests - just include `react` and `babel` (for JSX) to your `index.html`

```
// index.html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="/client/app.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
```

and now you can try `react`:

```
// app.jsx
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
      Hello, world!
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

but in this case you can't use packages installed through `npm` (can't use `import XXX from "YYY";` construction), you have to include them via `<script>` tag (like `react` and `react-dom` above)

## Installing React using NodeJs (CLI)

In this way you run frontend and backend separately, but keep files together.

> Express and React files sit on the same machine, and Express does double duty: it serves the React files, and it also serves API requests.
>
> https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-production/

To install React using CLI, you also need NodeJS to install.

Answer (score 1):

To make both run with single command you can add command like:

`"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run webpack --env.browser && cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run webpack -- --env.server && NODE_ENV=development node compiled/server.dev.js"`,

Then run command `npm run start`

And to watch all the directory changes you should add directory name in nodemon.json file like:

```
{
    "verbose": false,
    "watch": [
      "app/utils",
      "app/routes.jsx",
      "server",
      "webpack"
    ],
    "exec": "npm run start && node server.dev.js"
}
```